# Проблема с правами доступа + PHP + Windows 7

Tags: php

Написал скрипт для отправки файла по почте:

```
<?php
    $message = "Test message with attachment";
    $subject = "Hello World";
    $mailto = "starovoyt107@yandex.ru";

    $filename = $_POST['fl'];
    $path = "C:\OpenServer\userdata"; //В этой директории выбираю файл для отправки
    $file = $path.$filename;
    $content = file_get_contents($file);
    $content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
    $uid = md5(uniqid(time()));
    $name = basename($file);

    $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n";

    $nmessage = "--".$uid."\r\n";
    $nmessage .= "Content-type:text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
    $nmessage .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
    $nmessage .= $message."\r\n\r\n";
    $nmessage .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
    $nmessage .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"\r\n";
    $nmessage .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
    $nmessage .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"\r\n\r\n";
    $nmessage .= $content."\r\n\r\n";
    $nmessage .= "--".$uid."--";

    if (mail($mailto, $subject, $nmessage, $header)) {
        return true; 
    } else {
      return false;
    }

?>
```

Однако в итоге получаю ошибку:

> Warning: file_get_contents(C:\OpenServer\userdata): failed to open
>   stream: Permission denied in
>   C:\OpenServer\domains\localhost\send_mail.php on line 9

Я уже снимал на папку OpenServer атрибут "только для чтения" - не помогает, к тому же, галочка снова появляется... И ладельца через свойства менял, и галочки ставил, чтобы полный доступ был - не работает...

Comment: либо `"C:\\OpenServer\\userdata"` либо `"C:/OpenServer/userdata"`.

Answer (score 1):

1. либо `"C:\\OpenServer\\userdata"` либо `"C:/OpenServer/userdata"`.
2. `$file = $path.$filename;` добавить разделитель между путем и файлом. Должно быть так `$file = $path.'\\'.$filename;`, либо так `$file = $path.'/'.$filename;`, в зависимости от того, какой разделитель вам ближе.

PS Ну и в целом сделайте вывод получившегося значения `$file` и посмотрите, действительно ли такой файл есть

Comment: По первому пункту попробовал - без изменений.
По второму - не очень понял, как синаксически правильно в строчку $file = $path.$filename; добавить разделитель...

Comment: @user241926 дополнил ответ

Answer (score 1):

> Warning: file_get_contents(C:\OpenServer\userdata): failed to open
>   stream: Permission denied in
>   C:\OpenServer\domains\localhost\send_mail.php on line 9

сами выше пишите что это `C:\OpenServer\userdata` директория. А значит у вас `$filename = $_POST['fl'];` пусто в `$filename` и совету выше добавьте разделитель в   `$file = $path. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .$filename;`
где `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR = \ | /` знак `|` читать как или.